# Java Convert Asn.1 byte Array in convienient String for Browser

Tags: java, string, arrays, asn.1, pem

I try to convert a ASN.1 Byte Array into a String with Java. My results up to now:

```
byte[] asn = ocspResponse.getEncoded();
String liccert = new String(asn, "Cp850");
```

This String contains some String artifakts which are very disturbing:

Like this:

```
4¦20110416173611Z0üÏ0üi0:0
```

Is there a way to convert the byte Array like this:

```
RFMRIwEAYDVQQIEwlsb2NhbGhvc3QxFDASBgNV?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *absolutely* not convert arbitrary binary data to a string using the String constructor. That constructor is for taking binary data *which is actually encoded text* and building a string from it. Your data isn't really encoded text - it's just arbitrary binary data. Pretending it was originally text is a recipe for data loss.

The best approach is usually to [Base64 encode it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). There are plenty of third party libraries to do this, including [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) or [this public domain encoder](http://www.iharder.net/current/java/base64/).

For example, using the latter:

```
String liccert = Base64.encodeBytes(asn);
```